# How do I determine the version of a library in Unix without 'strings' or 'what'

Tags: unix, shared-libraries

I have a copy of the expat XML processing library on an embedded system running busybox 0.61.  I need to find out the version of the library, but I don't have the 'strings' or 'what' applications on the image, nor can I recompile the image.  These busybox images that I'm forced to use a grossly impaired.

Is there any way for me to find out what version of the expat library is installed without the 'strings' or 'what' utilities ? The library is shared (libexpat.so.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is just a one-time problem, couldn't you copy the library to another machine that has `strings` installed and run it there?

Comment: Sounds good to me.  I've worked with embedded systems where the easiest thing to do is often to `tftp` (dumb UDP-based protocol) files to and from a real workstation.

Comment: Even using an editor on some stripped-down systems can be painful; particularly if all you have to choose from is `ed` and `joe`. :)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to write your own equivalent of 'strings'. Versions aren't part of the elf format. Some libraries happen to contain a string with a version, others do not.

For expat in particular you might get a good idea by using nm to see what APIs are present and absent. Programmatically, that'd dlopen and dlsym.

Comment: These things don't even have 'nm' on them either, it turns out.  Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2):

If it is libexpat 1.95.0 or later, the library will have a `XML_ExpatVersion()` function which returns a `char *` containing the library version.

Answer (score 1):

Run `ident` against the library to find out what version it is. It is similar to `strings` but it picks out the revision source control library identifiers.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: A good suggestion, but it turns out I don't have 'ident' either.  I'm still discovering just how truly limited these boxes are.